# Android Studio | NEGOTIATE authentication error: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I was working with Android Studio 3.2 and everything was working fine few days back.

Now i have updated AS to 3.2.1 and I am not able to execute any gradle command.

Anyone out there fought with similar issue ?

```
./gradlew clean
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.10/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
NEGOTIATE authentication error: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)
NEGOTIATE authentication error: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)
NEGOTIATE authentication error: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)
NEGOTIATE authentication error: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)
NEGOTIATE authentication error: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)
NEGOTIATE authentication error: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)
```

This continues forever .......

Answer (score 0):

This error is showed because you are behind a proxy, and you didn't set up your proxy configuration under the **gradle.properties** or there is a problem with your authentication in that proxy

```
systemProp.http.proxyPort=
systemProp.http.proxyUser=
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=
systemProp.https.proxyHost=
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=
systemProp.https.proxyPort=
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=
systemProp.https.proxyUser=
```

Comment: Perhaps this is not the case. I remember fixing it by clearing the studio cache.

Answer (score 0):

I'll put a little two recommendations.

- Your Gradle version is a little outdated, upgrade that to a newer one.
- Invalidate Cache in the menu.
- Create a new project and move your files (resources, code & implementations in your current Gradle file) to there.

If this step didn't work, delete everything that's related to android studio and install it again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be using the wrong version of Java? 6 when it needs 7/8 or viceversa